# java infinite loop while using collections

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

Please suggest me to solve the below infinite loop . Class object contains the collection of same type objects. While converting to String , The object calls the toString of each object in the collection. Hence it leads to infinite loop.
Please dont use any static variables.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 *
 * @author ranga
 */
public class MyList  {
    LinkedList<Object> l1,l2;

    MyList() {
        l1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
        l2 = new LinkedList<Object>();
        l2.add(l1);
        l1.add(l2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return l1.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String ...args) {
        MyList m = new MyList();
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are adding one list to another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to prevent an infinite recursion in toString()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300203/most-efficient-way-to-prevent-an-infinite-recursion-in-tostring)

Comment: Why are you putting a list as element into another, and that crosswise?

Answer (score 2):

Don't add a linked list to itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you *intentionally* created a cyclic data structure as an example, and you really *do* want to be able to generate a String rendering of a cyclic graph.

The answer is not straightforward.

Firstly, you need to perform a traversal of a (potentially) cyclic graph without getting into a loop.  The basic algorithm is like this:

```
public void traverse(List<?> graph) {
    doTraverse(graph, new IdentityHashMap<?, ?>());
}

private void doTraverse(List<?> graph, IdentityHashMap<?, ?> visited) {
    if (visited.get(graph) == null) {
        visited.put(graph, graph);
        for (Object element : graph) {
            if (element instanceof List<?>) {
                doTraverse((List<?>) element, visited);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `visited` map allows the traversal to not visit nodes that it has already visited.

---

The second part of the problem is to modify the code to do the rendering.  And at this point you have to decide *how* you want to render the cycles in the graph ... in the context of the output being a sequence of characters.

The obvious way is to label things.  For example we could write a rendering of `l1` as

```
1: [2: [1] ]
```

(Each list is represented as a `[ ... ]` and `n:` means that the following thing has a "label" `n`.  When we encounter a "node" we have already seen, we use a the label; e.g. the 2nd `1` in the above refers back to the list we labelled as `1`.)

Given a representation like that, we can modify the `doTravers` method to take an extra `StringBuilder` argument, and change the `IdentityHashMap` to hold the label strings as values.  The rest is pretty straightforward.

The problem with this approach are:

- The rendering is not very readable ... especially for larger and/or more complicated graph structures.
- The algorithm needs to know how to do the traversal AND the rendering for the specific types involved.  It is difficult to implement this in a generic, data-structure-independent  fashion.

Answer (score 0):

IS it me or that recursivly calling ToString() methhod has always recursivly calls itself
and has not a single case when that recursive calll can stop ?
If so you need some condition to quit calling itself recursivly.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the `toString()` method. By default, it prints all elements in a collection by iterating over them (look in the implementation of [AbstractCollection.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29)). The problem that you are having is that by adding a list as an element to the other (and the other way around). When `l1` is printed, it calls the `toString()` method of `l2` (because that it is first element), which in turns prints the element one by one, and since `l2`'s first element is `l1` it calls the `toString()` method of it, and so on...

In short, don't short-circuit lists by adding them as elements to each other.